# print if not assigned

Tags: r

How can I write into a function a way to detect if the output is being assigned (`<-`) to something?  The reasoning is I'd like to print a message if it is not being assigned and just goes to the console but if it is being assigned I'd like it not to print the message.

Here's a dummy example and how I'd like it to behave:

```
fun <- function(x) {
    if (being_assigned) {
        print("message")
    }
    return(x)
}

#no assignment so message prints 
> fun(6)  
[1] "message"
[1] 6

#assignment so message does not prints
> x <- fun(6)
```

The `being_assigned` in the function is the imaginary unknown condition I'd like to detect but don't know how.

Comment: Is adding a flag argument to `fun` cheating...?

Comment: How is a function supposed to read the future?  Would you settle for `if(grep(my_source_code, return.my_variable.)) ...` (sorry about the crappy regexp there) ?  I know you're a reliable fella, but could you explain exactly what you are trying to do here?  There may be a much better way to go at it.

Comment: @Carl I stopped asking if with R and started asking how.  I know it sounds crazy (to me too) but the talent of R users makes things I don't think are possible possible.

Comment: I am attempting to print a message that is only semi important (it's stored with the data frame as a comment).  Not printing is more of an aesthetic thing.  If you're assigning to an object the console isn't muddied with output so it shouldn't print the message (IMO).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the best you can do is to define a special print method for objects returned by the function:

```
## Have your function prepend "myClass" to the class of the objects it returns
fun <- function(x) {
    class(x) <- c("myClass", class(x))
    x
}

## Define a print method for "myClass". It will be dispatched to 
## by the last step of the command line parse-eval-print cycle.
print.myClass <- function(obj) {
    cat("message\n")
    NextMethod(obj)
}

> fun(1:10)
message
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
attr(,"class")
[1] "myClass"
>
> out <- fun(1:10)
>
```

Comment: I think this is the best approach.  This actually is exactly what I want.  Kinda feel like a doof for not thinking of it myself.

Answer (score 2):

I love Josh's idea but for future posters wanted to show what I did which is a slightly modified version of his approach.  His approach prints out the class information which is the only thing I didn't like.  He used the `NextMethod` to avoid the infinite recursion printing.  This causes the

```
attr(,"class")
[1] "myClass"
```

to be printed.  So to avoid this I print the message first and then print 1 through the length of the class object (using indexing).

```
fun <- function(x) {
    class(x) <- 'beep'
    comment(x) <- "hello world"
    return(x)
}

print.beep<- function(beep) {
    cat(paste0(comment(beep), "\n"))
    print(beep[1:length(beep)])
}


> fun(1:10)
hello world
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Thanks again Josh for the idea.

If the reader didn't want the little `[1]` index to print either they could `cat` the output int he print statement as:

```
print.beep<- function(beep) {
    cat(paste0(comment(beep), "\n"))
    cat(beep[1:length(beep)], "\n")
}
```

Comment: A better method than using subsetting is to just strip the relevant class, and call `NextMethod` on the resulting, unclassed object.