# Reduce with less than symbol

Tags: r, higher-order-functions

I never think to use `Reduce` but I have a problem I thought it would be good for.  I want to make sure the size of each iterative element of a vector is equal to or larger than the previous element.  I can do this with `sapply` but my attempt with `Reduce` fails.  How can I use this with `Reduce`?

```
#This works
y <- c(1,2,3,2,4,4)
sapply(seq_along(y)[-length(y)], function(i) y[i] <= y[i+1])

#attempts
Reduce('<', c(1,2,3,2,4,4)), accumulate = TRUE)
Reduce('<', c(1,2,3,2,4,4)))
```

Comment: I don't think it can be used as `Reduce` will in general end up with something like `f(f(x[1],x[2]),x[3])`, so your comparison for the third element will be `TRUE < 3`. `identical(y,sort(y))` would appear to be the most efficient solution for this problem.

Comment: @James can you add that as a solution?

Comment: Or we could go the most difficult route and look for negative signs in the first derivative :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft As Gavin's answer shows I think that might actually be the cleanest/easiest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desparately bored? I was:

```
myFun <- function(x,z){
  if(is.null(names(z))) names(z) <- z
  if(is.null(names(x))) names(x) <- x
  if(as.numeric(names(x)) < as.numeric(names(z))) res <- TRUE else res <- FALSE
  names(res) <- names(z)
  return(res)
}
as.logical(Reduce(myFun, y, accumulate = TRUE)[-1])
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Boredom contest!  +1 .  Now I'm going to have to write a function that does a spline fit AND calculates the first derivative.

Comment: After other's comments I thought it wasn't possible.  Thank you for showing me `Reduce` isn't the best tool for the job.  This answers my question about `Reduce`.

Comment: @TylerRinker, as [you wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056392/print-if-not-assigned#comment17731844_13056392), ask not "if" but "how" ;) Perhaps "why that way?" is also a good question here, which would ultimately lead you to use one of the other suggested methods instead of using brute force like this answer!

Answer (score 5):

The `diff()` function would be a logical choice here (others having explained nicely why `Reduce()` is not appropriate). It is already set up to compare the differences between elements of a vector and is already vectorised.

```
> !diff(y) < 0
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Probably the fastest approach and perhaps the least amount of code. +1

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding from `?Reduce` that `Reduce` compares the first and second element. Since `1 < 2` returns `1`. It will reuse `1` and then compare it to the third element and so on. This means you will always compare `1 < y[3:length(y)]` which turns out to be always true. Alternatively you could try:

```
head(y,-1) < tail(y, -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it can be used as `Reduce` will in general end up with something like `f(f(x[1],x[2]),x[3])`, so your comparison for the third element will be `TRUE < 3`.

```
identical(y,sort(y))
```

would appear to be a more efficient solution for this problem.

Comment: No, `sort` is not the most efficient... If you want to check if a vector is monotonic, `all(diff(y) >= 0)` or even better `all(y == cummax(y))` are a lot more efficient. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093912/how-to-check-if-a-sequence-of-numbers-is-monotonically-increasing-or-decreasing/13094801#13094801

Comment: @flodel Nice, I'll edit it to *more* efficient. Do you want to add your remarks as an alternative answer?

Comment: Thanks James. Tyler wanted an answer about `Reduce` so I think a link in the comments will be enough.